# cost function diverging in batch gradient descent

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement the gradient descent method in python. I would like the calculation to stop when `abs(J-J_new)` reaches a certain tolerance level (i.e. it converges), where J is the cost function. The calculation will also stop after a set number of iterations. I have tried several different implementations, and in all of my attempts, the cost function actually diverges (i.e. `|J-J_new| -> inf`). This makes very little sense to me, and I cannot determine why it would be doing this from my code. I am testing the implementation with 4 trivial data points. I have commented it out for right now, but the `x` and `y` will eventually be read from a text file with over 400 data points. Here is the simplest implementation that I could come up with:

```
# import necessary packages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

'''
For right now, I will hard code all parameters. After all code is written and I know that I implemented the 
algorithm correctly, I will consense the code into a single function.
'''

# Trivial data set to test
x = np.array([1, 3, 6, 8])
y = np.array([3, 5, 6, 5])

# Define parameter values
alpha = 0.1
tol = 1e-06
m = y.size
imax = 100000

# Define initial values
theta_0 = np.array([0.0])   # theta_0 guess
theta_1 = np.array([0.0])   # theta_1 guess
J = sum([(theta_0 - theta_1 * x[i] - y[i])**2 for i in range(m)])

# Begin gradient descent algorithm
converged = False
inum = 0
while not converged:
    grad_0 = (1/m) * sum([(theta_0 + theta_1 * x[i] - y[i]) for i in range(m)])
    grad_1 = (1/m) * sum([(theta_0 + theta_1 * x[i] - y[i]) * x[i] for i in range(m)])
    temp_0 = theta_0 - alpha * grad_0
    temp_1 = theta_1 - alpha * grad_1
    theta_0 = temp_0
    theta_1 = temp_1
    J_new = sum([(theta_0 + theta_1 * x[i] - y[i])**2 for i in range(m)])
    if abs(J - J_new) <= tol:
        print('Converged at iteration', inum)
        converged = True
    J = J_new
    inum = inum + 1
    if inum == imax:
        print('Maximum number of iterations reached!')
        converged = True
```

Comment: It should be `J = sum([(theta_0 + theta_1 * x[i] - y[i])**2 for i in range(m)])`, right? Also, you don't need for loop when you have `numpy`.

Comment: And also, use more data, 4 sample points are definitely not enough to test your code, even if your code is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented with it a little more. The divergence was was happening because the learning rate, `alpha`, was too high. It also helped when I changed the way that I was checking for convergence. Instead of using `abs(J - J_new)` to check convergence, I am using `abs(theta0_new - theta_0)` and `abs(theta1_new - theta_1)`. If both of those are within a certain tolerance, then it has converged. I also re-scaled (normalized) the data, which seemed to help as well. Here is the code:

```
# import necessary packages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Gradint descent function
def gradient_descent(x,y,alpha,tol,imax):
    # size of data set
    m = y.size
    
    # Define initial values
    theta_0 = np.array([0.0])   # theta_0 initial guess
    theta_1 = np.array([0.0])   # theta_1 initial guess
    
    # Begin gradient descent algorithm
    
    convergence = False
    inum = 0
    
    # While loop continues until convergence = True
    while not convergence:
        
        # Calculate gradients for theta_0 and theta_1
        grad_0 = (1/m) * sum([(theta_0 + theta_1 * x[i] - y[i]) for i in range(m)])
        grad_1 = (1/m) * sum([(theta_0 + theta_1 * x[i] - y[i]) * x[i] for i in range(m)])
        
        # Update theta_0 and theta_1
        temp0 = theta_0 - alpha * grad_0
        temp1 = theta_1 - alpha * grad_1
        theta0_new = temp0
        theta1_new = temp1
        
        # Check convergence, and stop loop if correct conditions are met
        if abs(theta0_new - theta_0) <= tol and abs(theta1_new - theta_1) <= tol:
            print('We have convergence at iteration', inum, '!')
            convergence = True
            
        # Update theta_0 and theta_1 for next iteration
        theta_0 = theta0_new
        theta_1 = theta1_new
        
        # Increment itertion counter
        inum = inum + 1
        
        # Check iteration number, and stop loop if inum == imax
        if inum == imax:
            print('Maximum number of iterations reached. We have convergence!')
            convrgence = True
            
    # Show result   
    print('Slope=', theta_1)
    print('Intercept=', theta_0)
    print('Iteration of convergece=', inum)


# Load data from text file
data = np.loadtxt('InputData.txt')

# Define data set
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

# Rescale the data
x = x/(max(x)-min(x))
y = y/(max(y)-min(y))

# Define input parameters
alpha = 1e-02
tol = 1e-05
imax = 10000

# Function call
gradient_descent(x, y, alpha, tol, imax)
```

I have only checked it with that data set in that text file.